# Use Robocopy to backup specific users folders

Tags: backup, robocopy

This is my first question on StackOverflow, so please be kind ;); I have several computers to backup at different times, each computer has from 2 to 30 users, I want to backup Desktop, Documents and Favorites folders of a specific computer in the network.

Originally, I tried to use `XCOPY`, but due to the length of folder paths it could not be done, so I used `ROBOCOPY` instead, but I'm stuck. Here is what I have:

```
SET source=c:\testA\Users
SET dest=c:\testB               

rem Desktop folder backup

for /D %%G in (%source%\*) DO ( 
if exist "%%G\Desktop" ROBOCOPY /e /s /MIR /copyall  "%%G\Desktop" "%dest%\%%G\Desktop" )
```

This command can't create the destination folder `%dest%\%%G\Desktop` at run time this is like : `c:\testb\c:\testA\Users\"current username from for index %%G"\Desktop`.

It gives me error on destination folder: *"syntax of file name, dir name or volume name is incorrect."*
Theoretically the command itself works, apart from dest folder, but maybe I am missing something. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to answer my own question because of the length of the code.
I managed to get things working except for excluding directories i wanted to be excluded...

Here i am getting source and destination from user input:

```
 SET /p source="Hostname : "
 SET /p dest="Destination path : "
 SET /p _OS="a for XP b for W7 backup : "
 echo "you chose %_OS%"
```

IF condition to get correct Windows7 folders path based on previous choice:

```
    IF %_OS%==b ( 
        SET source=%source%\c$\Users
        pause

        echo !source!
        echo %dest%
        pause
```

FOR condition to loop through User folders:

```
            FOR /D %%G in (!source!\*) DO (
                if exist %%G\Desktop ROBOCOPY %%G\Desktop %dest%\%%G\Desktop /XD !source!\admin /e /s /copy:datsou

        )
        PAUSE
```

when the code is executed !source!\admin gets the correct path to be excluded, but robocopy just copies it anyway.
I also tried to specify the path : "\computer1\c$\Users\admin" with or without quotes, same effect, the path is not exlcuded.

Any ideas???

Comment: I am all alone it seems, I will keep writing, maybe this can be helpfull to someone. ROBOCOPY cannot exclude folders he is in, if the FOR index is pointing to the directory I want to exclude, robocopy cannot exclude it.       i.e  current path C:\Users\Admin\Desktop ---> /XD \Admin